# make 'textfield' readonly conditioned using ext js 3.3

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am using ExtJS 3.3 and I have the following code for my `formpanel`:

```
Ext.apply(this, {
    items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'ApplicationGUID',
            labelAlign: 'right',
            name: 'Application_GUID',
            value: 0,
            readOnly: false,
            width: 300
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'ApplicationName',
            labelAlign: 'right',
            name: 'Application_Name',
            anchor: '-20',
            msgTarget: 'side'
        }

    ], //eof items
    tbar: [{
        xtype: 'mydeletebutton',
        scope: this,
        ownerCt: this,
        handler: this.deleteHandler,
        myAuth: {
            compBaseRights: {
                Delete: {
                    failProperty: {
                        disabled: false
                    }
                } /*eof Delete*/
            } /*eof compBaseRights*/
        } /*eof sgAuth*/
    }, {
        xtype: 'tbseparator'
    }, {
        xtype: 'trashcanbutton',
        scope: this,
        ownerCt: this,
        handler: this.setIsDeletedHandler,
        myAuth: {
            compBaseRights: {
                Insert: {
                    failProperty: {
                        disabled: false
                    }
                } /*eof Delete*/
            } /*eof compBaseRights*/
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'mytrashcanrestorebutton',
        scope: this,
        ownerCt: this,
        handler: this.unsetIsDeletedHandler,
        myAuth: {
            compBaseRights: {
                Insert: {
                    failProperty: {
                        disabled: false
                    }
                } /*eof Delete*/
            } /*eof compBaseRights*/
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'tbseparator'
    }, {
        xtype: 'mysavebutton',
        scope: this,
        handler: this.saveHandler,
        myAuth: {
            compBaseRights: {
                Write: {
                    failProperty: {
                        disabled: false
                    }
                } /*eof Delete*/
            } /*eof compBaseRights*/
        }
    }],
    bbar: {
        xtype: 'mystatusbar'
    }
});
```

What I'm looking for is that for `textfield` Application_GUID, I need to be `readOnly: true` if a value already exist(like when I double click on an existing one from the grid in order to edit it), and if I press the new button from my `grid`, I need the `readonly` statement to be `false`.

If someone can help me , It would be grate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good technique is to set a boolean variable to initialise as false. Then set it to true according to your needs.

Then add the required listener like in the following example code, for example on the change listener:

```
listeners: {
    yourlistener: function(e) { //yourlistener can be change, select, etc...
        if (booleanVariable === true) Ext.getCmp('your-textbox-id').setReadOnly(true);
        else Ext.getCmp('your-textbox-id').setReadOnly(false);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> or use a boxready function then later use  change function to get
> events when clicked or not, then set the variable